# Error: com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton failed to instantiate.

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to run the Google Play Games Services samples, and I'm having a lot of trouble doing so.

Initially, trying to open the existing code projects via 'Import Existing Code into Workspace' in Eclipse was resulting in all sorts of errors that I couldn't figure out. Namely that the R.java wasn't building. I was able to work around that by just creating a blank project and copy-pasting all the code and resource files in.

So I have the project set-up, and I've referenced the `google-play-services_lib` and `BaseGameUtils`, so there are no errors showing up in MainActivity.java, and it'll all compile and build okay, but the layout editor keeps spitting out `com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton` failed to instantiate.

I've pasted the full stacktrace from the error below. I can't think of anything that I'm missing, and the only thing in the 'Problems' window in Eclipse is 'should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false' for the manifest.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F02000C.
at android.content.res.BridgeResources.throwException(BridgeResources.java:693)
at android.content.res.BridgeResources.getDrawable(BridgeResources.java:164)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.aa.b(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.aa.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.c(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.d(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview.renderSync(RenderPreview.java:560)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview.access$5(RenderPreview.java:506)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderPreview$RenderJob.runInUIThread(RenderPreview.java:1230)
at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Wasx this resolved? I still have this error

Comment: @Slartibartfast Restart eclipse is the solution.

Comment: In Android Studio, "Clear Cache" on preview screen worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm focusing on the first line of your trace for now :

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F02000C.
```

Whatever else may or may not be wrong, you need to fix this. Firstly, are you confident that no resources are missing from your project ? i.e. you built this project in an unusual way and it would not be surprising if you had missed out something.

If BaseGameUtils and the Google Play Services lib have been cleaned, defined as libraries and referenced in your project and compile ok then the problem is probably with your emulator.

Does you emulator have the Google APIs on it ?

Try restarting the emulator.

If everything looks ok, I suggest you review this document and the "troubleshooting guide" that is linked from it:
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/README.md and consider starting again from scratch going though each step carefully.

Comment: I wasn't even loading the application yet. The error was in the warnings pane of the Graphical Layout editor. Today that warning is no longer present, so that's weird.

The layout preview is still showing a pure white screen, however.

Comment: Okay, the white screen is apparently normal. I was able to boot the sample. Apparently all it took was restarting Eclipse to clear the could not instantiate error and fixing something I'd missed in the AndroidManifest to get the activity to start.

Comment: Yes - sometimes a "clean" is not sufficient. Good luck !

Comment: might not be conducive but if this is the answer why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similiar issue and I was also able to resolve it by restarting eclipse. But I am clueless as to why this worked. This may help some one.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two gradles...problem will be solved

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
```